# wkhtmltopdf not found - Golang Ubuntu

Tags: go, wkhtmltopdf

After trying lot of solutions for this error, I am posting this issue here. I have written a  method which converts html to pdf and returns pdf bytes as output.

```
import (
"bytes"
"github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf" 
)

func HtmlToPdf(htmlData *string) ([]byte, error) {
pdfg, err := wkhtmltopdf.NewPDFGenerator()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
pdfg.AddPage(wkhtmltopdf.NewPageReader(bytes.NewReader([]byte(*htmlData))))
//nolint: gomnd
pdfg.Dpi.Set(600)
jb, err := pdfg.ToJSON()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
pdfgFromJSON, err := wkhtmltopdf.NewPDFGeneratorFromJSON(bytes.NewReader(jb))
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

err = pdfgFromJSON.Create()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
pdfBytes := pdfgFromJSON.Bytes()

return pdfBytes, nil }
```

Calling this method returns error **wkhtmltopdf not found**
I have tried the following solutions

1. which wkhtmltopdf
   /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
   and then setting the WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf in environment section of my code
2. Using setPath at the top of HtmlToPdf Method like

   wkhtmltopdf.SetPath("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf")

In this case the error changes to fork/exec /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: no such file or directory

3. Also tried after moving the wkhtml files to /usr/local/go/bin/ and using path
   /usr/local/go/bin/wkhtmltopdf
4. Converting any url to pdf using command line also works fine.

Note : Hitting wkhtmltopdf --version in terminal gives wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt) and package is installed using go get github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf

Any other solutions?

Comment: instead of setting `PATH` as `/usr/local/go/bin/wkhtmltopdf` try setting it as `/usr/local/go/bin`

Comment: note that [WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH](https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf/blob/02f9cbe162f4af6f2890cc3f837d68de628521f1/wkhtmltopdf.go#L276) should point to directory not executable

Comment: Pointed the WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH to /usr/local/bin and printed the final path which is  /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf . File is present at this path still my method is returning the same error wkhtmltopdf not found

Answer (score 0):

hello in my case u should install [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) ,but if u are using MacOS so just install on terminal

> brew install wkhtmltopdf

and make sure path directory same like you installed wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

Check your program files for the wkhtmltopdf folder and move it to the C:\windows\ directory, then copy the

```
C:\windows\wkhtmltopdf\bin
```

path to the environment variable under the Path node.

Option 2

Find the installation path for wkhtmltopdf and copy the path till \wkhtmltopdf\bin and add it to the environment variable under the Path node, but if you have a space character in your folder path, make sure you add double quotes while adding the value.